# React Router including the colon (:) in the /path/:id, resulting in a failed fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to fetch information about a specific character on a page based on that character's id. The routes are defined as such:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

// import pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import SingleCharacter from "./pages/SingleCharacter";
import Error from "./pages/Error";
import Episodes from "./pages/Episodes";

//import components
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";


function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
          <About />
        </Route>
        <Route  path="/episodes">
          <Episodes />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/character/:id">
          <SingleCharacter />
        </Route>
        <Route  path="*">
          <Error />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, what ends up happening is that the Router includes the colon ':' in the path, making the actual url eg. https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/:2 instead of /character/2, resulting in a failed request with a 500 error code:

```
SingleCharacter.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
GET https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/:2 500       
SingleCharacter.js:18 :2
```

So the problematic line is

```
<Route path="/character/:id">
    <SingleCharacter />
</Route>
```

I've also console logged the id to make sure this is the reason, and when I manually enter the id without the colon, everything works as intended.

Here's my SingleCharacter.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import "./SingleCharacter.css";

const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/";

const SingleCharacter = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [character, setCharacter] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    async function getCharacter() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${url}${id}`);
        console.log(id)
        const data = await response.json();
        if (data) {
          const { name, image, status, species, origin, location, episode } =
            data;
          const newCharacter = {
            name,
            image,
            status,
            species,
            origin,
            location,
            episode,
          };
          setCharacter(newCharacter);
        } else {
          setCharacter(null);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    getCharacter();
  }, [id]);

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  if (!character) {
    return <h2>No Character to Display</h2>;
  }

  const { name, image, status, species, origin, location, episode } = character;

  const generateEpisodeNumber = (episodeLink) => {
    if (episodeLink.slice(-2) > 9) {
      return episodeLink.slice(-2);
    } else {
      return episodeLink.slice(-1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <section className="character-container">
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <img src={image} alt="character-portrait"></img>
      <div className="character-info-container">
        <p>
          <span className="character-data">Current status: </span>
          {status}
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="character-data">Species: </span>
          {species}{" "}
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="character-data">Origin: </span>
          {origin.name}
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="character-data">Last known location: </span>
          {location.name}
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="character-data">First appearance in episode: </span>
          {generateEpisodeNumber(episode[0])}
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default SingleCharacter;
```

I've managed to get it working by manually removing the colon by editing the url string (removing the first character, which is the ':' symbol):

```
const response = await fetch(`${url}${id.substring(1)}`);
```

This does work but it's obviously not a real solution, but rather a way to confirm that this is what causes undesired behaviour in the first place. It also creates further issues for nested routes branching from this component.

Comment: How do you navigate to that `/character` path?

Comment: @tromgy 

Hi, this question pointed me in the right direction and I ended up solving the issue. The problem was in the CharacterCard component which is the point from where I navigate to the /character path.

The colon was coming from the following line:

```<Link to={`/character/:${id}`} </Link>
```
Changing it to
```<Link to={`/character/${id}`} </Link>
```
fixed the issue.

Thanks!